# how to put the assign the right values in excel

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

i'm trying to assign cells of sheet1 values from sheet2 . the code works fine but im having a logical error coz im getting the wrong values.
ive tried different methods but none are giving me the right results.

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
sheet2 = wb['Sheet2']

count = 0
for i in sheet2.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    count += 1
    for value in i:
        sheet1['H23'] = value
        sheet1['H24'] = value
        sheet1['H25'] = count


wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

for example value in sheet2 A1,B1 is "test1,test2"
instead of getting sheet1['H23'] = test1 and sheet1['H24']=test2
im  getting sheet1['H23'] = test2 and sheet1['H24'] = test2

what i would like to get is sheet1['H23'] = test1 and sheet1['H24'] = test2

Comment: You are assigning exactly the same value to `H23` and `H24` and doing so for every cell in the row. What does the source row look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in sheet2.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    count += 1
    sheet1['H23'] = i[0]
    sheet1['H24'] = i[1]
    sheet1['H25'] = count
```

alright ... this solved it ... thanks anyways